# Test tab not shown beside the summary tab in Azure devops after completion of agent1 job

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, automated-tests

Test tab not shown beside the summary tab in Azure devops after completion of agent1 job.
I am executing an automation script written java and testng. Using Maven as project.
After running the agent job Test tab is not available beside summary tab.
[image]

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.